# MySQL: Average interval between records

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

Assume this table:

```
id    date
----------------
1     2010-12-12
2     2010-12-13
3     2010-12-18
4     2010-12-22
5     2010-12-23
```

**How do I find the average intervals between these dates, using MySQL queries only?**

For instance, the calculation on this table will be

```
  (
    ( 2010-12-13 - 2010-12-12 )
  + ( 2010-12-18 - 2010-12-13 )
  + ( 2010-12-22 - 2010-12-18 )
  + ( 2010-12-23 - 2010-12-22 )
  ) / 4
----------------------------------
= ( 1 DAY + 5 DAY + 4 DAY + 1 DAY ) / 4
= 2.75 DAY
```

Comment: This'll be _much_ easier without doing it in SQL. Why do you need it to be done in SQL?

Comment: Because it sounds like a fun thing to do. I've already implemented this with my PHP function. But I'm curious to see if it can be done with MySQL without a significant performance hit.

Comment: first of all you need to calculate diff between 2 rows look on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017468

Comment: Of course you do realize that you are calculating the average wrongly? If you have 4 intervals in the example, then dividing by 5 gives you something that is not an average length of an interval.

Comment: I meant dividing by the number of intervals, in this case, 5. C'mon dude, we learnt averaging back in what, the 5th grade.

Comment: You only have 4 intervals, "dude".

Comment: In this case it's 4, not 5. Unreason was right :)

Comment: =D - My bad! I was looking at the number of dates, not intervals.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Intuitively, what you are asking should be equivalent to the interval between the first and last dates, divided by the number of dates minus 1.

Let me explain more thoroughly. Imagine the dates are points on a line (`+` are dates present, `-` are dates missing, the first date is the 12th, and I changed the last date to Dec 24th for illustration purposes):

```
++----+---+-+
```

Now, what you really want to do, is evenly space your dates out between these lines, and find how long it is between each of them:

```
+--+--+--+--+
```

To do that, you simply take the number of days between the last and first days, in this case 24 - 12 = 12, and divide it by the number of intervals you have to space out, in this case 4: `12 / 4 = 3`.

With a MySQL query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(dt), MIN(dt)) / (COUNT(dt) - 1) FROM a;
```

This works on this table (with your values it returns 2.75):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `dt` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `a` (`dt`) VALUES
('2010-12-12'),
('2010-12-13'),
('2010-12-18'),
('2010-12-22'),
('2010-12-24');
```

Comment: D'oh, you're right! If you only have timestamps and not start/end pairs, there is no need for any aggregation shenanigans.

Comment: +1 for not following a pattern and seeing the problem for what it really is. :D

Comment: You sir, are a genius! This solution is the perfect example of achieving simplicity by thinking outside the box.

Comment: Nice! And what if the difference is only a couple of seconds between the entry? My result currently is `0,0000` so there seems to be a precision problem. EDIT: found `TIMEDIFF` for getting the number of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If the ids are uniformly incremented without gaps, join the table to itself on id+1:

```
SELECT d.id, d.date, n.date, datediff(d.date, n.date)
FROM dates d
JOIN dates n ON(n.id = d.id + 1)
```

Then GROUP BY and average as needed.

If the ids are not uniform, do an inner query to assign ordered ids first.

I guess you'll also need to add a subquery to get the total number of rows.

**Alternatively**

Create an aggregate function that keeps track of the previous date, and a running sum and count. You'll still need to select from a subquery to force the ordering by date (actually, I'm not sure if that's guaranteed in MySQL).

Come to think of it, this is a much better way of doing it.

**And Even Simpler**

Just noting that Vegard's solution is much better.

Comment: The alternative is a good start, let me see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns correct result

```
SELECT AVG(
        DATEDIFF(i.date, (SELECT MAX(date) 
                          FROM intervals WHERE date < i.date)
                 )
           )
FROM intervals i
```

but it runs a dependent subquery which might be really inefficient with no index and on a larger number of rows.

Comment: Quite inefficient, took about 2 seconds to run on 100 records. But does exactly what it's supposed to. Can we optimize this?

Comment: width sub queries there i'll be always the problem with slowliness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do self join and get differences using DATEDIFF function and get average.

Comment: There is no primary key on the table. So if I do self-join, how do I calculate using the next or previous row?

Comment: Yup! Don't ask me, I didn't design it.