# Get the two consecutive dates with the greatest period between them

Tags: php, mysql

```
$a = 1950-05-01
$b = 1965-08-10
$c = 1990-12-30
$d = 1990-12-29
$e = 2012-09-03
```

Dates are retrieved from a mysql database ordered by date ascending.

I need a mysql or PHP script to get the two ***CONSECUTIVE*** dates with the maximum days difference.

Explaination: Script should calculate the number of days between $a and $b, $b and $c, $c and $d, $d and $e, $e and $a, then output the two dates with the maximum days difference.

Is there a way to do this with a fast mysql/php code or should I make some loops with the following script (found it on another question here on stackoverflow)?

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Query that lists dates:

```
SELECT date AS count FROM table WHERE column1 = 'YES' AND data BETWEEN 1950-01-01 AND 2012-09-04
```

Comment: Please show the query that fetches those dates.

Comment: That query will return a single number (the number of records in `table` which satisfy the filter criteria), not a list of dates.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake :D I've updated the question

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178373/sql-query-to-get-difference-between-adjacent-records

Comment: @WeContest how is the ***order*** of "consecutive" dates determined?

Comment: @ZaneBien Records are ordered by date descending.

Comment: The question does not make sense! Those records cannot be ordered by date descending, otherwise the maximum difference is always between the first and last item. Please, try explaining the problem again and re-check the example data. It would help if you provide an example data and expected result. That works as a test case for any solution offered, too.

Comment: I agree with MikkoRantalainen. the $e and $a is not all satisfying. if u need it then there is no point of the entire hardwork.Go for maximum difference between the first and last item

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### MySQL Solution

Assuming that each date has a sequential `id`. See it [in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27a94/1).

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id tinyint,
  dt date);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES 
(1, '1950-05-01'),
(2, '1965-08-10'),
(3, '1990-12-30'),
(4, '1990-12-29'),
(5, '2012-09-03')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT a.dt AS date1, 
    (SELECT dt FROM tbl WHERE id = a.id - 1) AS date2,
    DATEDIFF(a.dt, b.dt) AS diff
FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.id = a.id -1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY diff DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
|                         DATE1 |                           DATE2 | DIFF |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| August, 10 1965 00:00:00-0700 | December, 30 1990 00:00:00-0800 | 9273 |
```

### PHP Solution

```
$array = array('1950-05-01', '1965-08-10', '1990-12-30', '1990-12-29', '2012-09-03');

$maxDiff = 0;
$maxStart = NULL;
$maxEnd = NULL;

for($i = 1; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
    if(isset($array[$i])) {
        $diff = (strtotime($array[$i]) - strtotime($array[$i-1])) / (60*60*24);

        if($diff > $maxDiff) {
            $maxDiff = $diff;
            $maxStart = $array[$i-1];
            $maxEnd = $array[$i];
        }
    }
}

echo "The maximum days difference is between $maxStart and $maxEnd, with a difference of $maxDiff days";
```

**Result**

```
The maximum days difference is between 1965-08-10 and 1990-12-30, with a difference of 9273.0416666667 days
```

**Update 1**

With regards to the PHP solution, if your dates are not in order, you can sort the array before the loop using `sort($array);`.

Comment: but the right answer would be date $a and date $e - in the php solution you should add the first value at the end of the array and also do an abs on the diff!

Comment: @DelPedro No, the OP is asking for *consecutive* dates.

Comment: yes but consecutive in the way they are written and not consecutive in chronological order - quote: "Explaination: Script should calculate the number of days between $a and $b, $b and $c, $c and $d, $d and $e, $e and $a, then output the two dates with the maximum days difference."

Comment: @DelPedro The way you're reading it, my PHP solution will work, minus the last `$e` and `$a` difference.

Comment: self joins are sweet, I must train myself. nice answer

Comment: `+1` nice answer. oh by the way, thanks for the [good example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176318/what-is-considered-incorrect-tagging)

Comment: @JW웃 Do you disagree with the discussion? I don't see any comments from you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this single-statement solution:

```sql
SELECT   a.date date1,
         b.date date2,
         DATEDIFF(b.date, a.date) ddiff
FROM     (
         SELECT     @a_rn:=@a_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_rn:=0) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) a
JOIN     (
         SELECT     @b_rn:=@b_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @b_rn:=-1) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) b ON a.ascrank = b.ascrank
ORDER BY ddiff DESC
LIMIT    1
```

---

## Query Breakdown

---

Given this example data-set:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  date DATE
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('1950-05-01'),
('1965-08-10'),
('1990-12-30'),
('1990-12-29'),
('2012-09-03');
```

We want to find the biggest difference between two consecutive dates (meaning, given the dates ordered in ascending order, find the maximum day difference of the dates and their *immediate* prior dates).

We would expect to output:

```
+-------------+------------+--------+
| date1       | date2      | ddiff  |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1965-08-10  | 1990-12-29 | 9272   |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Because the biggest *consecutive* date difference is between `1965-08-10` and `1990-12-29`.

---

### Step 1:

The first thing we want to do in order to get the previous and next dates beside each other (to facilitate the `DATEDIFF` function) is to attach a rank number to each date based on the ascending order of the dates.

Because the order of the dates can't rely upon anything but themselves (not an auto-incrementing ID or rank field, etc.) we must manually calculate the rank ourselves.

We do this by using MySQL variables. Other solutions that use variables require that you execute three or more separate statements. My technique of initializing the variables right in the query itself (via `CROSS JOIN`) keeps it contained in a single statement.

```sql
SELECT     @a_rn:=@a_rn+1 ascrank,
           date
FROM       tbl
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_rn:=0) var_init
WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
ORDER BY   date
```

*Renders:*

```
+----------+------------+
| ascrank  | date       |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 1950-05-01 |
| 2        | 1965-08-10 |
| 3        | 1990-12-29 |
| 4        | 1990-12-30 |
| 5        | 2012-09-03 |
+----------+------------+
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18eea/5)

Note the `WHERE` condition that the dates have to be in between two specified dates. This is where you would insert your start/end date parameters from your script.

---

### Step 2:

Now that we have ranked each date, we now need to perform a shifted inner join of the result onto itself based on the `ascrank` field so that we get the consecutive dates beside each other. We do this by wrapping the result in a subselect.

Since we need to self-join a derived result, we must duplicate the step above only with a slightly adjusted parameter:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     (
         SELECT     @a_rn:=@a_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_rn:=0) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) a
JOIN     (
         SELECT     @b_rn:=@b_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @b_rn:=-1) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) b ON a.ascrank = b.ascrank
```

*Renders:*

```
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| ascrank  | date        | ascrank  | date       | 
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 1        | 1950-05-01  | 1        | 1965-08-10 | 
| 2        | 1965-08-10  | 2        | 1990-12-29 | 
| 3        | 1990-12-29  | 3        | 1990-12-30 | 
| 4        | 1990-12-30  | 4        | 2012-09-03 | 
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18eea/6)

The "slightly adjusted parameter" is just that the ascrank variable (`@b_rn`) in the second subselect starts from `-1` instead of `0`. That way, the join condition of `a.ascrank = b.ascrank` joins the *next* date in the ascending order. We could have also kept both variables initialized at `0`, but joined on the condition of `a.ascrank = b.ascrank-1`, which would have rendered the same result.

**But wait, what happened to the date with the ascrank of `5`?** Since that is the last date in the order, there would be no dates after it to take the difference from, so it doesn't need to appear in the left side of the result, it only needs to be compared with its immediate prior date.

---

### Step 3:

Now that we have the consecutive dates beside each other, we can take the date difference (via `DATEDIFF()`) between the two:

```sql
SELECT   a.date date1,
         b.date date2,
         DATEDIFF(b.date, a.date) ddiff
FROM     (
         SELECT     @a_rn:=@a_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_rn:=0) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) a
JOIN     (
         SELECT     @b_rn:=@b_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @b_rn:=-1) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) b ON a.ascrank = b.ascrank
```

*Renders:*

```
+-------------+------------+--------+
| date1       | date2      | ddiff  |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1950-05-01  | 1965-08-10 | 5580   |
| 1965-08-10  | 1990-12-29 | 9272   |
| 1990-12-29  | 1990-12-30 | 1      |
| 1990-12-30  | 2012-09-03 | 7918   |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18eea/8)

---

### Step 4:

Now it's a simple matter of selecting the maximum `ddiff` value. We do this by using an `ORDER BY / LIMIT 1` technique on the `ddiff` field:

```sql
SELECT   a.date date1,
         b.date date2,
         DATEDIFF(b.date, a.date) ddiff
FROM     (
         SELECT     @a_rn:=@a_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_rn:=0) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) a
JOIN     (
         SELECT     @b_rn:=@b_rn+1 ascrank,
                    date
         FROM       tbl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @b_rn:=-1) var_init
         WHERE      date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'
         ORDER BY   date
         ) b ON a.ascrank = b.ascrank
ORDER BY ddiff DESC
LIMIT    1
```

*Renders:*

```
+-------------+------------+--------+
| date1       | date2      | ddiff  |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1965-08-10  | 1990-12-29 | 9272   |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo of Final Result*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18eea/4)

And we have arrived at our final result.

Comment: your query does not compare $e with $a like in the question mentioned.

Comment: @DelPedro, I believe that to be a mistake on the OP's part. With the fact that the dates are ordered in ascending order (as indicated by the OP in the question comments), if the first and last dates are allowed to be compared, then the maximum difference will ***ALWAYS*** be the difference between the first and last date... which is as simple as `SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date), DATEDIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date)) FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN '1950-05-01' AND '2012-09-04'`.

Comment: they are not ordered, $c > $d

Comment: @DelPedro, note that the OP is retrieving the dates using SQL without an `ORDER BY` clause, which may indicate that the OP's dates are being retrieved with no set order. Since we are doing this purely in SQL, the `ORDER BY` clauses in my solution take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the table scheme of njk - and checked it on my mysql db.

**SCHEME**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id tinyint,
  dt date);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES 
(1, '1950-05-01'),
(2, '1965-08-10'),
(3, '1990-12-30'),
(4, '1990-12-29'),
(5, '2012-09-03')
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, ABS(DATEDIFF(a.dt, b.dt)) AS ddiff
 FROM tbl AS a
 JOIN tbl AS b ON (a.id = (b.id + 1)) OR (a.id = (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AND b.id = (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))
 ORDER BY ddiff DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

I am joining all consecutive rows `(a.id = (b.id + 1))` and the first row with the last one like this: `(a.id = (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AND b.id = (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))` which looks strange but works very fine. In case you have only the 5 rows you mentioned this would be

```
 SELECT a.id, b.id, ABS(DATEDIFF(a.dt, b.dt)) AS ddiff
  FROM tbl AS a
  JOIN tbl AS b ON (a.id = (b.id + 1)) OR (a.id = 1 AND b.id = 5)
  ORDER BY ddiff DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

EDIT: The result is 1=$a and 5=$e

Comment: what if the id column is not unnecessarily with difference of 1?

Comment: @Angelin: yes, this query is dependent on a contiguous range of id values, which is something we cannot guarantee. The inclusion of a WHERE clause as in the OP query ( `WHERE column1 = 'YES'` ) makes it appear that some id values will be omitted).  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.dt,
  @dt_next := (SELECT dt FROM tbl WHERE dt > t1.dt ORDER BY dt LIMIT 1) dt_next,
  DATEDIFF(@dt_next, t1.dt) max_diff
FROM tbl t1
ORDER BY max_diff DESC LIMIT 1;

+------------+------------+----------+
| dt         | dt_next    | max_diff |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 1965-08-10 | 1990-12-29 |     9272 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just example:

```
mysql> SELECT MIN(version) AS version FROM schema_migrations UNION SELECT MAX(version) FROM schema_migrations;
+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 20120828071352 |
| 20120830100526 |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: But they won't be "*two consecutive dates*".

Answer (score 1):

if the dates are on a table you can do something like (this is not the T-SQL, its just an algorithm, to get the previous_date you would need to rn another select top 1 on the same table with an aclias X for example where X.date<=date)

```
select date, datediff(date, previous_date)
```

and order by the second column desc, so the first row would be the date you want

Answer (score 1):

Start with a subquery that creates a result set that has the dates in ascending order and an INT field (dateOrder) that starts at 1 and increments by 1.

```
SET @a := 0;
SELECT date, (@a:=@a+1) AS dateOrder FROM dateTable ORDER BY date
```

Now we can get consecutive dates by joining this result set to another copy of itself with a.dateOrder = b.dateOrder -1. In that result set, each row contains a pair of consecutive dates from the original table, and it is easy to calculate the difference and sort the result set to find the biggest difference.

```
SET @a := 0; SET @b := 0;
SELECT a.date as firstDate, b.date as secondDate, 
  datediff(b.date, a.date) AS difference FROM (
    SELECT date, (@a:=@a+1) AS dateOrder FROM dateTable ORDER BY date ) a JOIN (
    SELECT date, (@b:=@b+1) AS dateOrder FROM dateTable ORDER BY date ) b 
  ON a.dateOrder = b.dateOrder - 1
ORDER BY difference desc;
```

You can put a 'limit 1' clause at the end of the query to only get the first row, which has the biggest value of 'difference'. Note that you have to use two different variables to generate date order for the two subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Your query that returns date values is non-deterministic... absent an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, there is NO GUARANTEE that the rows will be returned in any particular order.

In MySQL, a query can return the result set you specified. Here is one approach:

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(d.mydate,@prev_date))  AS days_diff
     , DATE_ADD(@prev_date,INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS date1
     , @prev_date := d.mydate              AS date2
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_date := NULL) i
  JOIN ( SELECT d1.*
           FROM (            -- query to return rows in a specific order
                             SELECT mydate       
                               FROM mytable3 
                              WHERE 1
                              ORDER BY foo
                ) d1
          UNION ALL 
         SELECT d2.*
           FROM (            -- query to return rows in a specific order (again)
                             SELECT mydate
                               FROM mytable3 
                              WHERE 1
                              ORDER BY foo
                   LIMIT 1
                 ) d2
       ) d
 ORDER BY days_diff DESC
```

**NOTES:**

The `ABS()` function is needed only if you want to consider the number of days between the dates, irrespective of whether the first date is before or after the second date, since the `DATEDIFF` function can return a negative value.

The `DATE_ADD( ,INTERVAL 0 DAY)` function around the `@prev_date` user variable is just there to cast the return value to datatype DATE. A `STR_TO_DATE( ,'%Y-%m-%d') function would work as well. (The difference is that the DATE_ADD function will work with DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns without having to specify a format string to include hours, minutes, seconds.)

The inline views aliased as `d1` and `d2` contain the query that returns the list of dates in the SPECIFIED order you want the rows (dates) compared in.  You need the order of those rows to be deterministic if you want to guarantee a consistent result from the query.

The query in the inline view aliased as `d2` is identical to the query in `d1`, except for the addition of the LIMIT 1 clause.  Because you specified that you wanted to compare $e to $a, we "tack on" that first row from the query to the end so we can compare that first row with the last row from the query.

The `date1` column in the result set is not a DATE datatype, but it can easily be cast to a DATE

If you want other columns returned from the two rows, along with the date value, that can be easily handled using the same approach. The queries in `d1` and `d2` just need to return the additional columns:

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(d.mydate,@prev_date)) AS days_diff
     , @prev_foo                          AS foo1
     , @prev_date                         AS date1
     , @prev_foo  := d.foo                AS foo2
     , @prev_date := d.mydate             AS date2
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_date := NULL, @prev_foo := NULL) i
  JOIN ( SELECT d1.*
           FROM (            -- query to return rows in a specific order
                             SELECT mydate, foo
                               FROM mytable3 
                              WHERE 1
                              ORDER BY foo
                ) d1
          UNION ALL 
         SELECT d2.*
           FROM (            -- query to return rows in a specific order (again)
                             SELECT mydate, foo
                               FROM mytable3 
                              WHERE 1
                              ORDER BY foo
                   LIMIT 1
                 ) d2
       ) d
 ORDER BY days_diff DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

---

To setup test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable3` (`foo` varchar(1), `mydate` date);

INSERT INTO mytable3 VALUES 
('a','1950-05-01'),
('b','1965-08-10'),
('c','1990-12-30'),
('d','1990-12-29'),
('e','2012-09-03');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's PHP solution

```
$dates  = array('1970-05-01', '1975-08-10', '1990-12-30', '1990-12-29', '2012-09-03');
$sorted = array();

foreach($dates as $i => $date) {
    $date2 = isset($dates[$i+1]) ? $dates[$i+1] : $dates[0];
    $diff  = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date))/(60 * 60 * 24);

    $sorted[abs($diff)] = array('start' => $date, 'end' => $date2);
}

ksort($sorted);

$result = end($sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some simple PHP since it's quick and neat:

```
function get_the_two_consecutive_dates_with_the_maximum_days_difference($dates) {
    foreach ($dates as $i => $date) {

        $previousDate = $dates[$i - 1];
        if (!$previousDate) continue;

        $diff = strtotime($date) - strtotime($previousDate);
        if ($maxDiff < $diff) {
            $maxDiff = $diff;
            $dateA = $previousDate;
            $dateB = $date;
        }

    }
    return array($dateA, $dateB, $maxDiff);

}

// Usage
$arr = Array ( '2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-12', 
               '2012-05-10', '2012-08-05', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-04' );

var_dump(get_the_two_consecutive_dates_with_the_maximum_days_difference($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone for a solution using PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) class. The reason for this is that strtotime() does not have a way of specifying the format of the dates passed to it. In my mind this creates an ambiguity over what will be returned, so I have stopped using it in favour of DateTime.

As the example dates you gave are not in the correct order, I have assumed that they need to be sorted first. The following function achieves this:-

```
/**
 * Sorts an array of dates in given format into date order, oldest first
 * @param array $dates
 * @param type $format Optional format of dates.
 * 
 * @return array with dates in correct order.
 */
function sortArrayOfDates(array $dates, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($dates as $date){
        $timeStamp = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)->getTimestamp();
        $result[$timeStamp] = $date;
    }
    sort($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Now we can write a function to do the job:-

```
/**
 * Returns the longest gap between sets of dates
 * 
 * @param array $dates
 * @param string Optional. Format of dates.
 * 
 * @return array Containing the two dates with the longest interval and the length of the interval in days.
 */
private function longestGapBetweenDates(array $dates, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $sortedDates = sortArrayOfDates($dates);
    $maxDiff = 0;
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($dates) - 1; $i++){
        $firstDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $sortedDates[$i]);
        $secondDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $sortedDates[$i + 1]);
        $diff = $secondDate->getTimestamp() - $firstDate->getTimestamp();
        if($diff > $maxDiff){
            $maxDiff = $diff;
            $result = array($firstDate->format($format), $secondDate->format($format), $firstDate->diff($secondDate)->days);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

With your example list:-

```
$a = '1950-05-01';
$b = '1965-08-10';
$c = '1990-12-30';
$d = '1990-12-29';
$e = '2012-09-03';

var_dump(longestGapBetweenDates(array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)));
```

Output:-

```
array
  0 => string '1965-08-10' (length=10)
  1 => string '1990-12-29' (length=10)
  2 => int 9272
```

As a bonus my function gives you the number of days between the two dates too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select t1.date as 'Date1', t2.date AS 'Date2', DATEDIFF(t2, t1) as 'DateDiff'
From    YourTable t1
    Left outer join YourTable t2
        ON     t1.Id <= t2.Id 
            OR (t1.Id = (Select Max(Id) From YourTable) AND t2.Id=(SELECT Min(Id) From YourTable) )
    Left outer join YourTable t3
        ON t1.Id < t3.Id AND t3.Id < t2.Id
    WHERE t3.Id IS NULL
    ORDER BY 'DateDiff' DESC
    Limit 1,1
```

Answer (score -1):

For this to work around, use an array with this function:

```
<?php 
$date_array = array('1950-05-01','1965-08-10','1990-12-30','1990-12-29','2012-09-03');

function get_max_difference_dates($dates=array()){
    if(!count($dates)){
        return false;
    }
    $max_dates_diff = 0;
    $max_dates_diff_index = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($dates)-1;$i++){
        $temp_diff = strtotime($dates[$i+1]) - strtotime($dates[$i]);
        if($temp_diff>$max_dates_diff){
            $max_dates_diff = $temp_diff;
            $max_dates_diff_index = $i;
        }
    }
    return $max_dates_diff_index;
}

var_dump(get_max_difference_dates($date_array));
```

the answer to the above as per my compilation is `"1"`.

after the index you ca fetch the dates by the returned index and by adding one to it.

```
$indx = get_max_difference_dates($date_array);
$date1 = $date_array[$indx];
$date2 = $date_array[$indx+1];
```