# time difference between two similar values

Tags: mysql

I want to find the time difference between two function names in my database. the database looks like this:

[image]

what I want to do is to find the time difference between two consecutive function names who have the same name. for example the output will be for "getPrice" at row number "2" and row number "3" and then time difference for "getPrice"at row "3" and row "5" and so on for all other times and all other function names. Please help me and thanks a lot!

I tried

```
SELECT a.lid, a.date, (b.date-a.date) as timeDifference 
FROM myTable a 
INNER JOIN myTable b ON b.lid = (a.lid+1) 
ORDER BY a.lid ASC;
```

The problem is, it gives time difference for any consecutive function names even if they are not identical!

@tombom

there is a table I use for testing and have different variable names than the example I provided earlier. the table looks like this:

[image]

and after applying your code (and of course change the variable names to match with this table) the output looks like this:

[image]

as you can see the "getTax" is subtracted from "getPrice" although they are different. how can I solve this problem?? Thanks a lot.

the schema I'm trying to build is:

```
 CREATE  TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nserviceName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `functionName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NULL ,
  `tps` INT NULL ,
  `clientID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

and the insert is :

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('1', 'X1', 'getPrice', '2013-05-23 00:36:08', '22', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('2', 'X2', 'getTax', '2013-05-23 00:38:00', '33', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('3', 'X1', 'getPrice', '2013-05-23 00:35:00', '12', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('4', 'X1', 'getPrice', '2013-05-23 00:35:00', '11', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('5', 'X2', 'getTax', '2013-05-23 00:35:00', '88', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nserviceName`, `functionName`, `time`, `tps`, `clientID`) VALUES ('6', 'X1', 'getPrice', '2013-05-23 00:35:00', '33', '0');
```

thanks.

@tombom 
the operation I want to perform on the table is like the following image:
[image]

where I start from the first record X1 getPrice which have no record before it. so no operation is required. then check number two getTax have no getPrice before it which are not identical so again no operation will be performed. then number 3 getPrice have getTax before it so it ignores it and check above getTax to find getPrice here it will do the time difference between getPrice(#3) and getPrice(#1). next getPrice at row 4 will check the rows above it, and it find the one directly above it is getPrice so time difference between getPrice*(#4) and getPrice(#3) will be found. then getTax at row 5 will check the rows above it until it finds a similar functionName (getTax) which is at row #2. then the time difference between getTax at row 5 and getTax at row 2 will be found.

thanks a lot..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two rows and calculate the time difference between two timestamp values in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017468/how-to-combine-two-rows-and-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-timestamp)

Comment: If you're still stuck, consider providing a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @user1762447 I can see no "addTax" in there, I don't get it. Please provide an sqlfiddle as Strawberry suggested, or at least text values, no screenshots, so I can copy&paste. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ <- it has a pretty nice text-to-ddl-feature

Comment: I'm sorry there is no "addTax" I was meaning "getTax". I posted the schema I'm trying to built in my question. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT lid, `date`, serviceName, functionName, responseTime, sid, timeDifference FROM (
SELECT
IF(@prevFname = functionName, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`, @prevDate)), 'functionName differs') AS timeDifference,
@prevFname := functionName AS a,
@prevDate := `date` AS b,
yt.*
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @prevFname:=NULL, @prevDate:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY functionName, `date`
) subquery_alias
```

I like to use user defined variables in such cases as I made amazing experiences regarding performance, since no self-join is needed.

Also note that I used the `timestampdiff` function and `sec_to_time` to polish the output. `Timestampdiff` is the correct way to subtract different dates(+times). Only downside is, that `sec_to_time` only allows a range from '00:00:00' to '23:59:59'. If this can lead to problems, remove the function again. Read more about both functions on [this site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time).

**UPDATE** (less complicated than necessary):

```
SELECT lid, `date`, serviceName, functionName, responseTime, sid, timeDifference FROM (
SELECT
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @prevDate, `date`)) AS timeDifference,
@prevDate := `date` AS b,
yt.*
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @prevDate:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY lid
) subquery_alias
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This one resets the timedifference to `00:00:00` when functionName differs to previous one.

```
SELECT * /*choose here only the columns you need*/ FROM (
SELECT
IF(@prevFunction = functionName, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @prevDate, `time`)), '00:00:00') AS timeDifference,
@prevFunction := functionName AS a,
@prevDate := `time` AS b,
yt.*
FROM
test yt
, (SELECT @prevDate:=NULL, @prevFunction:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY id
) subquery_alias
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Okay, what a difficult birth. Just a minor tweak.

```
SELECT * /*choose here only the columns you need*/ FROM (
SELECT
IF(@prevFunction = functionName, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @prevDate, `time`)), '00:00:00') AS timeDifference,
@prevFunction := functionName AS a,
@prevDate := `time` AS b,
yt.*
FROM
test yt
, (SELECT @prevDate:=NULL, @prevFunction:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY functionName, id#, `time`
) subquery_alias
ORDER BY id
```

I order by function name and id again (or time if you prefer) in the subquery, do all the calculations, then sort it by id again in the outer query. That's it.

Comment: @user1762447 Feedback would be nice.

Comment: the program is great but there is two problems in it, and I'll really appreciate it .. first problem it subtracts the old record in the table from the new one so all the results are in negative. and the second problem is it doesn't subtract consecutive records with similar functionName... sometimes the output of the table is not arranged in consecutive order so the subtraction is with same functionName but not the exact record after it in time. Thanks ..

Comment: @user1762447 I misunderstood the question then. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, I still have some issue and I will post some snapshots of the original table I'm working on and the output after applying your query. Again, I really appreciate your effort and I hope if you can help me one more time. Thanks!

Comment: @user1762447 Updated my answer. Your sample data is not the best, as the timedifference is always zero. Anyways, I think now it should work like you want it to, unless I still didn't get it :)

Comment: I'm really really sorry, I think I'm not explaining myself clearly. I edited my question and put a snapshot for what I'm looking for... I really really appreciate your help. I know I asked a lot but I'm really have no clue how to sole it.. thank a lot, really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1762447 Okay, I think now we've got it. But please remember this for the future when you ask questions here. Problem - what you've tried - sample data - expected result. Don't forget to upvote :) Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks so much.. exactly what I was looking for and sorry for the vague explanation I will try to be clearer next time. thanks again.